# How to use a for loop to run sed -i on multiple files?

Tags: bash

My for loop is only editing the first file within the directory.

script:

```
    #!/bin/bash

for i in $1
do
        sed -i 's/$/\r/' $i
done
```

directory contains files `test1.txt` `test2.txt` `test3.txt` & `test4.txt`.

I'm trying to add carriage returns to each file, by editing each file.

To run the script:

```
./script.sh ./test*
```

I believe I'm not grasping what exactly the for loop is supposed to do, I thought it would loop through the files and run the command for each one...

Comment: Actually, the `for` loop doesn't help in this case because `$1` is only going to pick up `text1.txt`. That's because the shell automatically expands `./test*` before passing arguments to your script. It doesn't pass `./test*` as a single argument. `for i in $*` would make more sense. Using a variable name other than `i` here would make even more sense.

Comment: find pipe xargs pipe sed

Comment: Or just `sed -i 's/$/\r/' ./test*`. You don't really need a script or loop.

Answer (score 4):

Globs are expanded before the script runs. The following two invocations are identical:

```
./script.sh ./test*
./script.sh test1.txt test2.txt test3.txt test4.txt
```

So in other words, you have to loop over all arguments `"$@"` and not just `$1`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in "$@"
do
    sed -i 's/$/\r/' "$i"
done
```